# Azure PowerShell Connect-AzureAD and Login-AzureRmAccount

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I have a PowerShell script which uses Connect-AzureAD and also Login-AzureRmAccount.
Even though both use the same credentials, I get asked to enter them twice. Is there any way to only prompt the user once and use the same credentials for both cmdlets?

Comment: depending on how you auth that might be possible

Comment: well, by calling one of the cmdlets, a pop-up to enter email and password appears - thats how I authenticate

Comment: you can automate live id login, if you are using live id that's not possible, you need to use cert\ad user\service principal

Answer (score 2):

This finally worked for me

```
$cred = Get-Credential
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $cred
```

it does not display the neat Microsoft login screen but works for my scenarios

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work if you are using two-factor authentication to log in to Azure.